# Visual Studio 2022 Community - Address Sanitizer "Failed to use and restart external symbolizer"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2022, address-sanitizer

I am building a C++ project and trying to run the sanitizer. It is a fairly big project so I can't say exactly where the sanitizer fails, but the problem is that the sanitizer itself is unable to show the line.

Instead I get this error:

```
==17532==AddressSanitizer CHECK failed: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\asan\llvm\compiler-rt\lib\asan\asan_thread.cpp:361 "((ptr[0] == kCurrentStackFrameMagic)) != (0)" (0x0, 0x0)
==17532==WARNING: Failed to use and restart external symbolizer!
    #0 0x7ffc7df4a62d in _asan_wrap_GlobalSize+0x57567 (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX64\x64\clang_rt.asan_dbg_dynamic-x86_64.dll+0x18005a62d)
    #1 0x7ffc7df0a28f in _asan_wrap_GlobalSize+0x171c9 (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX64\x64\clang_rt.asan_dbg_dynamic-x86_64.dll+0x18001a28f)
    #2 0x7ffc7df4f809 in _asan_wrap_GlobalSize+0x5c743 (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX64\x64\clang_rt.asan_dbg_dynamic-x86_64.dll+0x18005f809)
    #3 0x7ffc7df26161 in _asan_wrap_GlobalSize+0x3309b (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX64\x64\clang_rt.asan_dbg_dynamic-x86_64.dll+0x180036161)
    #4 0x7ffc7df250e2 in _asan_wrap_GlobalSize+0x3201c (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX64\x64\clang_rt.asan_dbg_dynamic-x86_64.dll+0x1800350e2)
    #5 0x7ffc7df27375 in _asan_wrap_GlobalSize+0x342af (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX64\x64\clang_rt.asan_dbg_dynamic-x86_64.dll+0x180037375)
    #6 0x7ffc7df4878d in _asan_wrap_GlobalSize+0x556c7 (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX64\x64\clang_rt.asan_dbg_dynamic-x86_64.dll+0x18005878d)
    #7 0x7ffc7df33edb in _asan_wrap_GlobalSize+0x40e15 (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX64\x64\clang_rt.asan_dbg_dynamic-x86_64.dll+0x180043edb)
```

It says that a check failed, however if failed to get some symbolizer. I assume it means it failed to symbolicate the error site and to display the exact function where the issue is?

My internet connection is OK and I was not prompted to connect to any symbol servers. Do I have to manually download some symbols?